# Difference b/w JMS host and JMS server

Tags: java, jms, message-queue

Is there any difference b/w **JMS host** and **JMS Server(Broker)** . Or they represent the same thing the ***JMS Server*** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is JMS Host?

> A JMS host refers to a Message Queue broker.

source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beaog/index.html

What is JMS Server?

> JMS servers are environment-related configuration entities that act as
>   management containers for the queues and topics in JMS modules that
>   are targeted to them. A JMS server's primary responsibility for its
>   destinations is to maintain information on what persistent store is
>   used for any persistent messages that arrive on the destinations, and
>   to maintain the states of durable subscribers created on the
>   destinations.

source: http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24401_02/taskhelp/jms_servers/ConfigureJMSServers.html

So these two terms actually refer to same entity.

Comment: The term that is confusing is Message Queue,because in JMS destination may be either queue or topic

Comment: You are absolutely right. But it is sure that they refer to the same thing.